# Why two undefined macros are considered equal in GCC without a warning?

Tags: android, c++, c, macros, android-source

Considering the following code, what do you think the result could be? And what do you expect the result to be?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if AAAA == BBBB
    #define STRING "foo"
#else
    #define STRING "bar"
#endif


int main() {
    printf("%s\n", STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

Build and test:

```
~/test$ gcc -Wall test.c 
~/test$ ./a.out 
foo
```

I know it is technically correct since both AAAA and BBBB are "UNDEFINED", and it is up to the developer to make sure to check if both macros are defined before using it, but I really **expect the gcc could give a warning when I specified -Wall**. But it doesn't.

This is really a problem, and it makes sense. Image if you are using macros like *__BIG_ENDIAN* and *__BYTE_ORDER* to decide the endianess of you program should use, this might be a very problem leading issue.

For example, I found this kind of code exist in SKIA library in AOSP:

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    #define SK_CPU_BENDIAN
    #undef  SK_CPU_LENDIAN
#else
    #define SK_CPU_LENDIAN
    #undef  SK_CPU_BENDIAN
#endif
```

If you trying to port some of code snippet from this library and failed to include the correct headers(endian.h in this case), you are screwed...